# How do I get_posts from an Archive in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, get, if-statement

So, I successfully can get_posts from categories, but what about archives?  I need to say IF <= 5 posts in an archive, get this footer.  It works for categories, I just need to get the archive.  Keep in mind I'm using archive.php, NOT archives.php.

This is the code I used to get posts from a category:

```
<?php
   $cat = get_query_var('cat');
   $posts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat));

     if(count($posts) >= 5) {
       get_footer( 'home' );
     }
     else if(count($posts) < 5){
      get_footer();
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you echo-ed the `$cat` variable to see what it contains?

I am not sure  `get_query_var('cat');` will return what you need in your archive.php page. Anyways, I am asking you to use:

```
echo '<pre dir="ltr">';
    print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
  echo '</pre>';
```

so that you can have an idea about your main query object and its variables. Compare `$cat` with the corresponding field in the resulting array.

In all cases, use a code source with the appropriate arguments based on what you have in `$GLOBALS['wp_query']`.

Good luck